# Is it possible to consume the Search API using application token credentials?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, full-text-search, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-files

I need to do searches within SharePoint Online document libraries either using the new Search API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-overview) or using the `_api/search` endpoint.

I've reached a dead end using the `_api/search` endpoint as it seem it doesn't accept application token credentials even with certificate authentication. It ends up giving a `{"error_description":"Unsupported security token."}`

So, maybe the new Search API can be used to search elements within SharePoint Online document libraries from an external service.

However, the permission type `Application` is not supported as its said in the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Any hints on this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, you cannot use the Application token for this API for now as its is not supported as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions). You can try [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) as it supports application permissions as specified in the document.

Comment: but you cannot search based on SharePoint metadata, can you?

Comment: The above API which I mentioned mainly searches for the driveItem's fields including filename, metadata, and file content.:)-

Comment: But what about managed metadata, SharePoint columns and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing searches using the v1.0 Graph REST API. The link you have is to their beta release of the search query, which as you can see if you navigate there has a lot of warnings.

I have used this endpoint for searching file names and it has been working so far:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
```

If your pursuit takes you to search properties other than file names you will have to come up with your own iterative solution.